# How to configure facebook to enable "facebook login" for a django server?

Tags: django, facebook, oauth, django-allauth

I have difficulites to configure the facebook developer page in order to use the "facebook authentication" for a web site based on django and django-allauth.

Here is the Context :

```
DNS : www.mysite.com
Subdomain  for development : dev.mysite.com redirected to XX.XX.XX.XX :8000
```

The server is running on my windows PC  behind a simple home router. I launch it with the usual command:

```
Django runserver 0.0.0.0 :8000
```

The connection to server : dev.myste.com is OK

But the click on « login with facebook » button gives this error:

```
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
```

The Facebook configuration is:

Settings/basic :

```
App Domains= mysite.com
Site url : dev.mysite.com
```

Product/login:

```
Client OAuth Login : Yes
Web OAuth Login: Yes
Embedded Browser OAuth Login : Yes
Force Web OAuth Reauthentication : No
Valid OAuth redirect URIs: http://dev.mysite.com
Login from Devices: No
```

Thank you for you help and attention.

Comment: Go check what the _actual_ value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in your login dialog call is – _that_ URL (minus the URL-encoding applied to pass the value in the login dialog URL) is the one you need to specify as Valid OAuth Redirect URI.

Comment: Hi CBroe, 5 minutes ago i was unable to understand your comments. Now thanks to you and Firebug i found the solution. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using Firebug, i see that the django server sends to facebook the following oauth request.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email&state=RXBpz0X5agrX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FXX.XXX.XXX.XX%3A8000%2Faccounts%2Ffacebook%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&response_type=code&client_id=ABCDEFGF

Notice redirect_uri parameter in the request.
I add the redirect_uri parameter to the field "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" in the facebook/login page and it works immediately.